# Invalid ⁠ prisma.listing.findMany() ⁠ invocation:

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, prisma, next.js13

I'm developing a Next.js 13 application, utilizing Prisma as my ORM to interact with a MongoDB database. I've encountered an issue when trying to use the prisma.listing.findMany() method to retrieve data from my database. Despite following the Prisma documentation and ensuring my setup is correct, I'm faced with an error that I can't seem to resolve.

```
import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';

export interface IListingsParams {
  userId?: string;
  startDate?: string;
  startTime?: string;
  category?: string;
}

export default async function getListings(params: IListingsParams) {
  try {
    const { category, userId, startDate } = params;

    let query: any = {};

    if (userId) {
      query.userId = userId;
    }

    if (category) {
      query.category = category;
    }

    if (startDate) {
      query.NOT = {
        reservations: {
          some: {
                startDate: { lte: startDate },
          },
        },
      };
    }
    const listings = await prisma.listing.findMany({
      where: query,
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'desc',
      },
    });

    const safeListings = listings.map((listing) => ({
      ...listing,
      createdAt: listing.createdAt.toISOString(),
    }));
    return safeListings;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

```
schema.prisma

// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

type Feature {
  service String
  price   Int
}

model User {
  id                String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name              String?
  email             String?       @unique
  emailVerified     DateTime?
    verifyToken       String?
  verifyTokenExpiry DateTime?
  isVerified         Boolean? @default(false)
  image             String?
  hashedPassword    String?
  phoneNumber       String?       @unique
  createdAt         DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime      @updatedAt
  favoriteIds       String[]      @db.ObjectId
  accounts          Account[]
  listings          Listing[]
  reservations      Reservation[]
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Listing {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title         String
  description   String
  imageSrc      String
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  category      String
  time          String?
  bathroomCount Int?
  guestCount    Int?
  // locationValue String
  userId        String    @db.ObjectId
  price         Int
  // featureOne String?
  // featureTwo String?
  features      Feature[]

  user         User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  reservations Reservation[]
}

model Reservation {
  id         String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId     String    @db.ObjectId
  listingId  String    @db.ObjectId
  startDate  DateTime
  features   Feature[]
  endDate    DateTime?
  totalPrice Int
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now())
  startTime  DateTime
  endTime    DateTime?
  user       User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  listing    Listing   @relation(fields: [listingId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  otp        Int
}
```